# React Native Native Module - Passing JSON prop to Swift UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm creating a Native Module in my RN project which includes a view with a JSON prop like so:

```js
<MyNativeView name={{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }} />
```

The view is built in Swift and I have a setter for the `name` prop. Here's my current setup

```objectivec
// MyNativeViewManager.m
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyNativeViewManager, RCTViewManager)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(name, NSDictionary *)
@end
```

```swift
// MyNativeViewManager.swift
@objc(MyNativeViewManager)
class MyNativeViewManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return MyNativeView()
  }

  // ...
}

// MyNativeView.swift
class MyNativeView: UIView {
  @objc(setName:)
  func setName(name: NSDictionary) {
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?

    // This feels ugly... but does the job
    if let firstNameProp = name["firstName"] as? String {
      firstName = firstNameProp
    }

    if let lastNameProp = name["lastName"] as? String {
      lastName = lastNameProp
    }

    // Do stuff...
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to convert this property into a `struct` so I can nest additional JSON or throw an error if particular fields are missing.

If I'm understanding the docs correctly, it looks like I could use `RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY` and `RCTConvert` to convert a property into a defined type, but I'm not clear on how to do this in conjunction with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```swift
/// Custom View (Swift)
@objc
class MyNativeView: UIView {
  
  @objc
  func setName(nameParts:[String: String]) {
    // your logic..
  }
}
```

```swift
/// View Manager (Swift)
@objc(MyNativeViewManager)
class MyNativeViewManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return MyNativeView()
  }
}
```

```objectivec
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyNativeViewManager, RCTViewManager)

RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(name, NSDictionary, MyNativeView) {
  // do your validation....
  
  // Post validation
  // 'json' is the parameter you will get here and whose type is NSDictionary
  // 'view' is the current view and whose type is MyNativeView
  [view setNameWithNameParts:json];
}

@end
```